# selecting a value in one column based on minimum and maximum timestamp in R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a R data table with columns for timestamp, status, type and value

I need to select the value when timestamp is min (the first one of the day) and status is 1 and type is A.

I tried : `min(dt$timestamp[dt$status ==1 & dt$type == 'A']$value)`

Data table :

```
timestamp   status  type    value
01-02-2020 08:09:10 1   A   2
01-02-2020 08:19:34 0   A   3
01-02-2020 08:34:10 0   A   4
01-02-2020 09:09:33 0   B   5
01-02-2020 10:09:10 1   B   2
02-02-2020 05:06:11 1   B   3
02-02-2020 08:09:10 1   A   4
02-02-2020 09:02:11 1   A   4
02-02-2020 10:29:15 0   A   6
```

Expected output : If I want for date `01-02-2020`, Then `minimum timestamp` when `status == 0` and `type == A` is  `01-02-2020 08:19:34`. The corresponding value is 3

If I want for date `02-02-2020`, Then `minimum timestamp` when `status == 0` and `type == A` is  `02-02-2020 10:29:15`. The corresponding value is 6

I should be able to provide the required date.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `date` column and filter the values according to condition.

```
library(data.table)

want_date <- as.Date('2020-02-02')
setDT(df)[, date := as.Date(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y %T")]
df[date == want_date,value[timestamp == min(timestamp[status == 0 & type == "A"])]]
#[1] 6
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("01-02-202008:09:10", "01-02-202008:19:34", 
"01-02-202008:34:10", "01-02-202009:09:33", "01-02-202010:09:10", 
"02-02-202005:06:11", "02-02-202008:09:10", "02-02-202009:02:11", 
"02-02-202010:29:15"), status = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A"), 
value = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I need it only for specific date

Comment: Should I give  `df[, .SD[timestamp == min(timestamp[status == 0 & type == "A"])], date == '01-02-2020']`

Comment: And I need the data from `value` column when timestamp is min

Comment: Actually I wanted to get just the value as output not a table. I want to use this value in other table operations

Comment: Updated the answer to return only `value`.

Comment: `Error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Comment: @VJD Please add your data using `dput` if you have trouble applying the solution to your data.

Comment: @VJD I updated the data that I am using for this answer. Can you check if it works for you using this data? If it does work using this data but doesn't work for your real data can you compare and verify what is the difference between the two data?

Comment: My date is in this format : `YYYY-MM-DD` . I am getting `Error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types`

Comment: @VJD But that is not what you showed in the example shared. Hence, it is important that we have the exact data that you are using to resolve this. Can you please share data or part of data using `dput` ?

Comment: I tried converting the data. And I am printing it inside a loop. Now I got `numeric(0)
numeric(0)
[1] 299
[1] 299
[1] 344
[1] 344`

Comment: Also I got a warning : `Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d'
2: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

Comment: @VJD our discussion in comments will not produce anything useful if you are not ready to share data. As I have shown that my answer works for the data I have shared. To debug the issue you are facing I would need your data.